# AssemblyInfo versioning ignored in ASP.NET MVC Web App?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, reflection

Strange one here.  My MVC Web Application's version number is not printing correctly to my view according to what is set in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.  The definition I have set in set `AssemblyInfo.cs` is '`1.0.232.0`'.

I have tried multiple methods in order to print it:

```
<%= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()%>
```

(results 0.0.0.0)

```
<%= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()%>
```

(results in 2.0.0.0, which is set nowhere in my project.)

```
<%= typeof(HomeController).GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()%>
```

(results in 2.0.0.0)

This leads me to believe that it simply must not be picking up my AssemblyInfo.cs file?  This is also the case if I attempt to use the "Publish" button to publish to IIS on our development server.

Any ideas? Perhaps I'm using the wrong statement to fetch the version number? :\

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The view is (by default) still largely compiled on-demand, so you con't reliably use `GetExecutingAssembly()` within the view - however, for me the controller usage works fine:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]
```

with:

```
<h2><%=typeof(MvcApplication4.Controllers.HomeController).Assembly
   .GetName().Version.ToString() %></h2>
```

shows

### 1.2.3.4

in the page.

**edit**
The mistake you made was calling `typeof(...).GetType()` - that is going to give you `Type` (or a subclass) - so yes, it will be 2.x.
**/edit**

For the extra step of pre-compiling the views, see "MSBuild Task for Compiling Views" [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-mvc-design-gallery-and-upcoming-view-improvements-with-the-asp-net-mvc-release-candidate.aspx).

Arguably, your view shouldn't be fetching this data itself anyway - it should be put into the ViewData (or similar), perhaps by a base-controller or action-filter.

---

Re the question about master pages; first, pick a key ;-p

```
<%=ViewData["AppVersion"] %>
```

then two options leap to mind: override `OnActionExecuting` in the controller (or a common base-controller):

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["AppVersion"] =
            GetType().Assembly.GetName()
            .Version.ToString(); // probably cached
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

or create an action-filter:

```
public class AppVersionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(
         ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["AppVersion"] =
            GetType().Assembly.GetName()
            .Version.ToString(); // probably cached
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And mark your controllers (classes) or actions (methods) with this attribute:

```
[HandleError, AppVersion]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc! I know what you mean about GetType(), Darn to think I was that close! All working now and yes arguably it could be in my ViewData, however with a MasterPage how best could I achieve this?

Comment: A simple typeof(HomeController).GetType().Assembly.ToString() would have revealed I was inspecting mscorlib! That will be one to keep in mind.